# How to get webpage URL using php

Tags: php, html

I have a php script webpage let's say abc.php @['localhost/abc.php']
in abc.php i used this

```
<?php
echo $link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
?>
```

i include this page in another php webpage for example xyz.php @[localhost/123/xyz.php]
 but when i load xyz.php webpage i got this output

```
http://localhost/abc.php
```

while i want that my xyz.php webpage give me output this

```
http://localhost/123/xyz.php
```

Or if any GET request in xyz.php page then like this

```
http://localhost/123/xyz.php?q=searchthis
```

i tried many things , but unable to solve this problem

Comment: Which things did you try? What went wrong?

Comment: almost all $_server[] and other methods, but not getting what i need and i try this also 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461338/get-url-of-calling-webpage-in-php?rq=1

:(

Comment: Did you try vijay4vijju's suggestions below? In PHP, [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) is the "full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned." [Try it here.](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cmi-f1e)

Comment: i did.. it's useless.. give the main file path,,, not the calling webpage path..

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This will give you the requested directory and file name. If you use `mod_rewrite`, this is extremely useful because it tells you what page the user was looking at.

If you need the actual file name, you might want to try either `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, the magic constant `__FILE__`, or `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`. The later 2 give you the complete path (from the root of the server), rather than just the root of your website. They are useful for includes and such.

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` gives you the file name relative to the root of the website.

```
 $relative_path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 $complete_path = __FILE__;
 $complete_path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```

Comment: as i already meantioned in my question, i used this in my script, but it not giving the url of calling webpage..

Comment: Please show which of theses you've tried, what they output, and how that output differs from what you want.

Comment: all man..!! all $_server function and all suggested things, u have any suggestion... ??????

Comment: "All" does not tell us what you tried or what it outputs. Please edit your question to include that *specific* information.