# get url of page calling function from included file php

Tags: php

I am trying to get the url to the php file that calls a function. for example

```
//page1.php
<?php
     require 'page2.php';
     somefunction();
?>

//page2.php
<?php
     function somefunction(){
          echo //some way to find calling pages url
     }
?>
```

is this possible?

I have tried `$_SERVER['request_uri']`, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`, `__FILE__`, `$_SERVER['REFERER']` however none of these give me the info I'm trying to get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get URL of calling webpage in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461338/get-url-of-calling-webpage-in-php)

Comment: I would have thought the `REQUEST_URI` would provide that.  What does it show you?

Comment: check the`$_SERVER` if there is anything you want but beware that lots of data cannot be trusted

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you need. Could you pass `$_SERVER` to the function as an argument from page 1 to page 2? Alternatively are you looking for something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: REQUEST_URI will get the requested webpage however both of these files are serving as template files and are not necessarily going to be at that URI address

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it thanks to @The Humble Rat. im not sure this is the best way to handle this sort of task but I used the debug backtrace to select the file. the main thing is catching backtrace at a place where the file is going to be the same.
so in each function that can be called from another function I used this function

```
if(!function_exists('foil_uri')){
    function foil_uri(){
         //use index: 1 because 0 will be the trace when this function is called
        return dirname(debug_backtrace()[1]['file']);
    }
}
```

as long as this is called in the function that was called in the parent file you should get the correct directory. again i am not sure this is the best way to handle this situation if anyone else has a better solution please contribute